# Didn't appear image preview when send website link to direct message in instagram

Tags: html, web

When I send a site link in the direct message, preview image didn't appear. The title and description appear only. Maybe I need put some meta-tags to my html page? But when I share link to facebook or Twitter they show good.

Comment: I'm using that meta-tags
<meta property="og:type" content="{{ogtype}}"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ogtitle}}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ogdesc}}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ogimage}}"/>

Comment: What's the output of `{{ogimage}}`?  Also, are you aware that open graph requires a fully qualified URL? http://ogp.me/

Comment: ogimage - it's full link with https<br/>
https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_450/.../main%2Fsochialshare-cja9ldrc70008j4qkk5iawcpw